# ParseInt 16 radix number to 10 radix

Tags: javascript, parsing

Why?

> parseInt((1015217480013237**7**).toString(16),16) ==
>   1015217480013237**6**

Where the number of lost?

Comment: WHY parseInt("10152174800132377") == 10152174800132376

Comment: [See this question for more information.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 4):

The number is lost, as it is to large to be representable exactly in JavaScript's [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) type (it is a IEEE 754 double):

```
$ node
> 10152174800132377
10152174800132376
```